# difference between wtpwebapps and webapps II

Tags: tomcat, web-applications

I am new to the Eclipse wtpwebapps thing and am learning this practice in my new project. What I found out is that, if I directly copy project folders under wtpwebapps into traditional installed tomcat webapps folder, then startup tomcat .bat file, the application does not start as I expected it to. I am trying to start the server directly use the "target" folder content after "mvn clean install".

Answer (score 0):

The wtpwebapps (web tools platform) is an Eclipse tooling kit. It organizes files in Eclipse specific way. They think it is easier for a developer to organize files in that manner.
However, Tomcat needs files organized as per JEE specifications. So when you build a war from wtp project, the war generated will be as per JEE specifications and you can copy >that< to Tomcat.
Now if you are interested in seeing or modifying wtp(you don't need to), you can right click on project and in context menu change the default mappings of wtp project.
This is JEE spec layout:

MyWebApp (dir)
   * WEB-INF (dir)
     * web.xml
     * classes (dir)
     * lib (dir)
   * index.jsp

WTP, or Server Tools, maps it's structure to this structure above.
Also, read [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseWTP/article.html) great tutorial on how to develop and deploy with WTP.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by going to Eclipse severs tab, expand the server, then choose the "Modules" tab, then "add external web module", over there, I point the document base to the physical path of mvn target folder. run the server and the app starts.